# Calling Julia GTK from commandline/.bat with arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, julia

I'm trying to get my Julia script to start the command line

window.jl

```
using Gtk
showall(GtkWindow())
```

If I call this script through julia the window appears and stays until I close it.

```
include("window.jl")
```

However when I call this script from the command line, the window shows but immediatly closes.

```
C:\> julia path/window.jl
```

I discovered that if I call the file with the -L flag it shows the window as desired. However I am not able to pass any command-line arguments to window.jl anymore, since it assumes my arguments as other files to be opened by julia.

```
-L, --load <file>         Load <file> immediately on all processors
C:\> julia -L path/window.jl      (works!)
C:\> julia -L path/window.jl Arg1 (error could not open file Arg1)
```

Why would loading the file on all processors show the desired effect? How can I call the script that I can pass both arguments and keep the window showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see the window close immediately is that, once your script finishes executing, Julia quits and this cleans up everything started by that process. You need to force Julia to keep running until you close the window yourself. This is covered [here](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl#usage-without-the-repl) in the Gtk.jl documentation.